# Gecko I have ReferenceError: $ is not defined StackTrace

Tags: c#, jquery, gecko

I am trying to jquerify gecko web page to ExecuteJQuery but I am facing error saying: ReferenceError: $ is not defined StackTrace: @:1:1 don't know what i should do to fix that

```
GeckoScriptElement scriptJQuery = geckoWebBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script") as GeckoScriptElement;
scriptJQuery.Type = "text/javascript";
scriptJQuery.SetAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js");
scriptJQuery.Src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js";
geckoWebBrowser.Document.Head.AppendChild(scriptJQuery);
geckoWebBrowser.ExecuteJQuery("$('[name=\"message\"]').text('Something goes here');");
```

Comment: EITHER `scriptJQuery.SetAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js");` OR `scriptJQuery.Src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js";` not both. Also VERY old jQuery lib (7 years old?)

Comment: removed SetAttribute("src",""); function and changed jquery source to : scriptJQuery.Src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
still facing the same issue!

Comment: have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036383/how-to-load-another-jquery-version-from-geckowebbrowser-control

Comment: still didn't work ;(

Comment: ExecuteJQuery is really a thing? - you have `Gecko.JQuery.JQueryExecutor JQexecutor = new Gecko.JQuery.JQueryExecutor(GeckoBrowser.Window);
try
{
   JsVal value = JQexecutor.ExecuteJQuery(@"$.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js', function(){ alert('Script loaded and executed.'); });"); 
}
catch (Exception ex) { string exMessahe = ex.Message;  } `

Comment: it gave me the same error message: "JSError : ReferenceError: $ is not defined StackTrace: @:1:1"